# PHP Data sorting

Tags: php, mysql

For a statistics table, I am pulling the data to be the last 5 records with DESC over SQL. But the data I shoot comes in the form of 6,5,4,3,2. When I take it as ASC, I get the first 5 records instead of the last 5 records. Take the last 5 records by sorting the data I want to make as 2,3,4,5,6

The function I use

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `username`='".$username."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5")
```

In summary ; The last data I pulled as ASC is listed upside down on the Chart, I want it to be sorted as 2,3,4,5,6

[The result I got now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed3gr.png)

Comment: Reverse the results in PHP. You could do that with SQL, but that requires a subquery, which would be a waste of ressources for such a simple task.

Comment: Try limit 0,5 https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: Please use a prepared statement, hard-coded sql query escaping is a security risk.

Comment: When I use ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0.5, I get the result you use. https://prnt.sc/rdhgrd selects the first 5 records instead of the last 5 records

Comment: It's best to just reverse the order in PHP. I see no reason to do it in the DBMS, since you're already fetching only what you need, and usually delegating too much for the DBMS to do results in complex, slow and memory hogging SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sort will be done in MySQL can use next:

```
SELECT tmp.* FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE `username`='".$username."' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just pulling a small set, just use PHP built in functions like sort or any other function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

If it is a large data set, i'd avoid try to do that directly on the query, something like this:

```php
$db->bind('username',$username);

$query = $db->query('
      SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `username` = :username ORDER BY id DESC
     ) qry ORDER BY id'
);
```

I didnt test the query, but i would something similar to this.